# How can prevent my ajax function to add one after the other select box by initializing select2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, jquery-select2

I am adding some data via ajax and I am initializing select2 to my element after success. 
My problem is that everytime I change the `.project select`, another `.icon select` is created. So if I change the `.project select` 10 times I have 11 `.icon selects` on my page. But I need only one.

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
     $(document).off("change", ".project").on("change", ".project", function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "update.php",
                data: {
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                   $("#result").html(data);
                 $(".icons").select2({
                    templateResult: formatState,
                    templateSelection: formatState_select
                  });
                }
            })
       });
```

update.php:

```
 <select class="icons">
       <?php include('icons.php'); ?>
 </select>
```

index.php

```
<select class="project">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
 $(document).off("change", ".project").on("change", ".project", function (event) {

            $(".icons").select2('destroy'); 
            $.ajax({
                url: "update.php",
                data: {
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                   $("#result").html(data);
                 $(".icons").select2({
                    templateResult: formatState,
                    templateSelection: formatState_select
                  });
                }
            })
       });
```